# How to normalize a model.matrix?

Tags: r, model.matrix

```
# first, create your data.frame
mydf <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(1,2,3), c = c(1,2,3))

# then, create your model.matrix
mym <- model.matrix(as.formula("~ a + b + c"), mydf)

# how can I normalize the model.matrix?
```

Currently, I have to convert my model.matrix back into a data.frame in order to run my normalization function:

```
normalize <- function(x) { return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))) }
m.norm <- as.data.frame(lapply(m, normalize))
```

Is there anyway to avoid this step by simply normalizing the model.matrix?

Comment: What's `m`? Is that `mym` or some transformed data set?

Comment: @DavidArenburg m is a real-world representation of mym.  m is from my actual code, whereas mym is something I made up for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can normalize each column without converting to a data frame with the `apply` function:

```
apply(mym, 2, normalize)
#   (Intercept)   a   b   c
# 1         NaN 0.0 0.0 0.0
# 2         NaN 0.5 0.5 0.5
# 3         NaN 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

You probably actually want to leave the intercept untouched, with something like:

```
cbind(mym[,1,drop=FALSE], apply(mym[,-1], 2, normalize))
#   (Intercept)   a   b   c
# 1           1 0.0 0.0 0.0
# 2           1 0.5 0.5 0.5
# 3           1 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work well.  However, can you explain or simplify the syntax around `mym[,1,drop=F]`?  I don't understand what that's doing.  Also, why is `mym[,-1]` needed in the apply()?

Comment: I see that mym[,-1] is used because you don't want to normalize the "(Intercept)" column.  But, what about the mym[,1,drop=F]?

Comment: I see now, `drop 
logical. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension. The default is to drop if only one column is left, but not to drop if only one row is left.`  Basically, we are just combining the normalized columns with the original Intercept column.

Comment: @user1477388 You got it.

Comment: I don't think the drop is actually need here. The `cbind` function converts a numeric vector to a column-matrix.

Comment: @BondedDust I just used it to keep the name of the column. Yeah, you'll get the correct data regardless.

Comment: Ah, your subtle maneuver was lost on my coarse approach. Well played.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to vectorize this using the very useful `matrixStats` package (though TBH`apply` is usually very efficient too on matrices and when applied on columns). This way you get to keep your original data structure too

```
library(matrixStats)
Max <- colMaxs(mym[, -1]) 
Min <- colMins(mym[, -1])
mym[, -1] <- (mym[, -1] - Min)/(Max - Min)
mym
#   (Intercept)   a   b   c
# 1           1 0.0 0.0 0.0
# 2           1 0.5 0.5 0.5
# 3           1 1.0 1.0 1.0
# attr(,"assign")
# [1] 0 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "normalize" in one sense you can just use the `scale` function which centers and sets the std.dev to 1.

```
> scale( mym )
  (Intercept)  a  b  c
1         NaN -1 -1 -1
2         NaN  0  0  0
3         NaN  1  1  1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 2 3
attr(,"scaled:center")
(Intercept)           a           b           c 
          1           2           2           2 
attr(,"scaled:scale")
(Intercept)           a           b           c 
          0           1           1           1 
> mym
  (Intercept) a b c
1           1 1 1 1
2           1 2 2 2
3           1 3 3 3
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 2 3
```

As you can see, it doesn't really make sense to "normalize" all of the model matrix when the "Intercept" term is present. So you could instead do this:

```
> mym[ , -1 ] <- scale( mym[,-1] )
> mym
  (Intercept)  a  b  c
1           1 -1 -1 -1
2           1  0  0  0
3           1  1  1  1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 2 3
```

This is actually the model matrix that would result if your default contrasts option was set to "contr.sum" and the columns were factor type.  This only gets accepted as an internal-to-`model.matrix` operation if the variables to be "normalized" are factors:

```
> mym <- model.matrix(as.formula("~ a + b + c"), mydf, contrasts.arg=list(a="contr.sum"))
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contrasts.arg[[nn]]) : 
  contrasts apply only to factors
> mydf <- data.frame(a = factor(c(1,2,3)), b = c(1,2,3), c = c(1,2,3))
> mym <- model.matrix(as.formula("~ a + b + c"), mydf, contrasts.arg=list(a="contr.sum"))
> mym
  (Intercept) a1 a2 b c
1           1  1  0 1 1
2           1  0  1 2 2
3           1 -1 -1 3 3
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 1 2 3
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$a
[1] "contr.sum"
```